# Integrating ember application into a non-ember application

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have built an ember application which has two routes say route1 and route2.

I got the compiled files from dist folder. I put those files in a tomcat server.

When i try to access that file through index.html, it works fine. But how can i navigate to a route in that compiled application?

Normally in ember-cli development environment, we navigation to a route using server:port/route_name

How can i perform the same operation in index.html without using any hyperlinks for routes?

**Edit:**

Got the answer. Setting ENV.locationType = 'hash' solved the navigation problem. I was able to access the route using index.html#/route_name

But I am still stuck with how to integrate ember app into a non-ember app.

Comment: How can I insert a particular route in a jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

Setting ENV.locationType = 'hash' solved the navigation problem. I was able to access the route using index.html#/route_name

Setting ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing' solved inserting ember app into non-ember app. Create a div with the rootElement ID and then ember will automatically place the app inside the div.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: FYI I am the one who posted this question.. There are two questions in it.. I tried to figure out the solution for the former one.